# mt_rand with same numbers PHP, does it matter?

Tags: php, random

I am coming across having to use mt_rand where both numbers are the same,

It is in a while loop, I get no errors doing this, but would it be better using an if statement to stop the mt_rand from running, or would it be less cost effective to just run it like

```
 mt_rand(5, 5);
```

The while loop can have upto 50,000 loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: test both. If the difference is significant, do it.